# Cucumber tests configured in main method are not executing from jar file

Tags: cmd, automated-tests, cucumber, maven-plugin

I have a BDD maven project for API testing. I want to execute the cucumber tests independently by/from anywhere. To do this I required two things:

**1.** *A jar (I have built it via assembly plugin and maven-jar-plugin also )*
[image]

**2.** *A class having main() method OR Runner classes. (I have defined both in my framework)*

[image: Java class containing main() method]

*Runner Class:*

[image]

**3.** While running the command in cmd it is giving the error

- java -jar dealflow-bdd-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar 
  [image]

**Note:** By following the approach discussed in this question
[Running Cucumber tests directly from executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149977/running-cucumber-tests-directly-from-executable-jar)
I am able to create the jar by [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/dependency-info.html) but the error seems to change. Now by running

> java -jar dealflow-bdd-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar

it is giving this

[image]

**Comment:** Tests are running if I run the main() method directly from the IDE itself or Run the Runner class

Comment: For running from jar file, Just pass the features folder name instead of full path. The features folder should be kept under resources folder.

Comment: for the first option u need to add the relevant cucumber jars to the classpath

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried command with classpath as well "java -cp dealflow-bdd-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar;lib/* com.project.dealflow.bdd.runner.Execute" but it is also giving the same error