# Java executable jar file with missing package and its contents

Tags: java, maven

I inherited java maven project composed of **cucumber, junit and selenium** frameworks which I am new to except Junit. I noticed its pkg name is under **src/test/java** instead of **src/main/java**.

```
src/test/java
    com.somewhere.test
        FooRunner.java
```

I was told that I can run junit test from FooRunner class by right click **Run as > Junit Test** in eclipse IDE.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/com/sowhere/test/features",tags = {"@Test"}, plugin = {
    "pretty",
    "junit:target/results.xml",
    "html:target/cucumber"},
    dryRun = false)

public class FooRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
  }
}
```

I was able to run its unit test just fine. My question is I need this mvn project to generate **executable jar** file then be able to run its unit test from

```
java -jar Foo.jar
```

I followed this thread to [Running Cucumber tests directly from executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149977/running-cucumber-tests-directly-from-executable-jar) by updating **pom.xml** file and adding **public static void main** method however when I executed the jar file I received following error msg..

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.somewhere.test.FooRunner
```

I changed jar to zip then unpacked it all. Surprisingly I didn't see pkg name **com.somewhere.test** but I see other pkgs of external libraries such as cucumber and etc. Yes **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** is there with proper data I believe.

I am curious to know why the pkg (i.e. com.somewhere.test) is missing along with class (i.e. FooRunner.class)

**Update:**

I found an answer from this thread: [How can I include test classes into Maven jar and execute them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047637/how-can-i-include-test-classes-into-maven-jar-and-execute-them)

Comment: please update your pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Maven has a **src/main/java/** whose classes go into the product jar, and **src/main/test/java/** whose classes go in a test jar (or are just tested), not needed to run the application. This separation makes sence. The test jar depends on the production jar too, as it tests those classes.

This [test jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) can be created with goal **jar:test**