# how to run cucumber test from java main method?

Tags: gradle, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-java

i have below code

```
package runner;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PiccoloRunnerMain {

    private static String[] defaultOptions = {
            "--plugin", "pretty",
            "--plugin", "html:target/fix-api-results.html",
            "--plugin", "summary",
            "--glue", "cukestep",
            "--tags", "@T1",
            "src/main/resources/features/"
    };

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Stream<String> cucumberOptions = Stream.concat(Stream.of(defaultOptions), Stream.of(args));
            io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(cucumberOptions.toArray(String[]::new));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

but after generating uberjar file using gradle , when i run test its throwing error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must exist: /Users/abcd/repo/qa-orchestra/src/main/resources/features
```

how I to pass feature file to cucumber cli?

```
task uberJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "$mainClassName"
    }
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
    baseName(project.name)
    with jar
}
```

this is how I am generating jar file. or this is the issue with jar?

Answer (score 0):

answer is here in one of the comments.
[Running Cucumber tests directly from executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149977/running-cucumber-tests-directly-from-executable-jar/67926439#comment121350267_67926439)